# java.lang.NullPointerException at FaceletViewHandlingStrategy$MethodRetargetHandlerManager$ArbitraryMethodRegargetHandler.retarget

Tags: jsf, nullpointerexception, composite-component

I have created a JSF Composite Component to validate some phone numbers. If I place the raw code directly on the page everything works, but when I try to use the code in a CC I get an NPE on the page load.

The CC:

```
<!-- INTERFACE -->
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute required="true" name="gridID"/>
    <cc:attribute required="true" name="coutry"/>
    <cc:attribute required="true" name="listener"/>
    <cc:attribute required="true" name="number"/>
    <cc:attribute required="true" name="validator"/>
    <cc:attribute required="true" name="groupID"/>
</cc:interface>

<!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
<cc:implementation>
    <h:panelGrid id="#{cc.attrs.gridID}" 
                 columns="5">

        <h:outputText  value="Telephone*:"
                       styleClass="field-label"
                       style="margin-right: 22px"/>  
        <pou:selectOneMenu value="#{cc.attrs.coutry}" 
                           effect="fade"
                           required="true"
                           requiredMessage="Telephone country is required">  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{web['W0033']}" 
                          itemValue="" />  
            <f:selectItems value="#{worldCountriesUtilMb.listAll()}"/> 
            <pou:ajax listener="#{cc.attrs.listener}" 
                      update="#{cc.attrs.groupID}" />
        </pou:selectOneMenu>

        <pou:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.number}"
                       required="true"
                       requiredMessage="Telephone number is required"
                       style="margin-left: 10px">
            <pou:ajax event="keyup" 
                      listener="#{cc.attrs.listener}" 
                      update="#{cc.attrs.groupID}" />

        </pou:inputText>

        <h:panelGroup id="#{cc.attrs.groupID}"
                      style="margin-left: 10px">
            <pou:graphicImage value="#{publicURLGeneratorMb.s3Icon('cross-grey-1.svg')}"
                              width="20"
                              height="20"
                              rendered="#{!cc.attrs.validator}"/>

            <pou:graphicImage value="#{publicURLGeneratorMb.s3Icon('tick-blue-1.svg')}"
                              width="20"
                              height="20"
                              rendered="#{cc.attrs.validator}"/>

            <!-- Phone number validation -->
            <h:inputHidden value="#{cc.attrs.validator}"
                           validator="booleanTrueRequired"
                           required="true"
                           requiredMessage="Please make sure the phone number is valid."
                           rendered="#{!cc.attrs.validator}"/>

        </h:panelGroup>

    </h:panelGrid>
</cc:implementation>
```

How I am using it:

```
<ez:phone-validator 
    gridID="panelGrid3" 
    coutry="#{profileMb.roleOneProfileObj.phoneNumber.country}" 
    listener="#{profileMb.roleOneProfileObj.phoneNumber.validatePhoneNumber()}" 
    number="#{profileMb.roleOneProfileObj.phoneNumber.localNumber}" 
    groupID="valid-number" 
    validator="#{profileMb.roleOneProfileObj.phoneNumber.validNumber}"/>
```

Stacktrace:

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy$MethodRetargetHandlerManager$ArbitraryMethodRegargetHandler.retarget(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:1767)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.retargetMethodExpressions(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:731)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.CompositeComponentTagHandler.applyNextHandler(CompositeComponentTagHandler.java:201)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:196)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:196)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:196)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:178)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:395)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:366)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:111)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:196)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:320)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:379)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:358)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:155)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:164)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:870)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: It's not possible to quickly answer the question without seeing the stacktrace as that basically contains the answer. You should not ignore exceptions as if they are decoration if you can't interpret them.

Comment: You need to put a detailed description of your NPE (e.g. where it happens, the managed bean, etc.)

Comment: Again, if you can't interpret exceptions, don't ignore them as if they're decoration.

Answer (score 7):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy$MethodRetargetHandlerManager$ArbitraryMethodRegargetHandler.retarget(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:1767)
```

Based on [the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.16/com/sun/faces/application/view/FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java#1767),

```
1767                methodSignature = methodSignature.trim();
```

this will be thrown when `<cc:attribute>` in question doesn't have a `method-signature`.

Based on the code posted so far, the `<cc:attribute name="listener">` is the one which requires that. So, if you add that, then this problem should be solved.

```
<cc:attribute required="true" name="listener" method-signature="void listener()" />
```

Comment: Thanks, ironically this was part of the final solution but wasn't in fact what was causing the original NPE. It turns out that the original NPE was caused because the name 'validator' appears to be reserved. If I change it to anything else it works perfectly but if I call it 'validator' it generates the NPE.